# Selecting Records with Only One Value Occurring Within a Range

Tags: sql

Each week I send a large quantity of eggplants from my eggplant farm to my various customers. Customers usually purchase the same number of eggplants weekly, but occasionally that amount varies. Since I have over 25,000,000 customers (big farm), I want to condense their purchase information into a more manageable table for the report I'm working on. Here's what my source data looks like -

CustAcct -------------- PurchaseWeekEndDate ----- EggplantsPurchased

```
 123                  1/1/2012                    50

 123                  1/8/2012                    50

 123                  1/15/2012                   50

 123                  1/22/2012                   60

 123                  1/29/2012                   50

 123                  2/5/2012                    50
```

I would like the data in my new table to look like this -

CustAcct-------      StartRangePWEnd Date-----     EndRangePWEndDate      ------EggplantsPurchased

```
 123            1/1/2012           1/15/2012                50

 123            1/22/2012          1/22/2012                60

 123            1/29/2012          2/5/2012                 50
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the criteria for partitioning the ranges?  I see no apparent set of conditions that would result in the second grouping, plus the `EggplantsPurchased` column values do equal the collected subtotals from your first dataset.  And finally, why on earth would you want to do this?  It makes your data *much* harder to manage, not easier in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather hard problem.  To solve it, you need to identify groups of orders that are the same.  You can do this using a correlated subquery, to find the next date for each customer that has a different number of eggplants.  This works as a group identifier.

Once you have that, the rest is just aggregation:

```
select CustAcct, min(PurchaseWeekEndDate), max(PurchaseWeekEndDate), EggplantsPurchased
from (select t.*,
             (select min(PurchaseWeekEndDate)
              from t t2
              where t.CustAcct = t2.CustAcct and t.EggplantsPurchased <> t2.EggplantsPurchased and t2.PurchaseWeekEndDate > t.PurchaseWeekEndDate
             ) as nextDate
      from t
     ) t
group by CustAcct, nextDate, EggplantsPurchased
```

And, since no eggplant farm in the world has 25,000,000 customers, what is the real nature of this question?

Comment: Gordon - Thanks. I'll try this when I get to work in the AM. I'm a novice at SQL - been doing it four months - so it's nice to know the question wasn't completely simple. This is actually  benefits disbursement data for a government agency. EggplantsPurchased is a weekly benefit allowance that changes occasionally for claimants - generally less than one time per 26-week claim. Because these changes are so rare, I hope to create a derived table that's around 96% smaller than it would be were I leaving each payment as a separate record. This is for an SSRS report, and load time is important.

Comment: I thought this would require some sort of recursive partition and ranking operation, but I didn't get far with that.

Comment: @ChadMarsh . . . Unfortunately, even window functions are not much help, until you get to cumulative sums (SQL Server 2012, Oracle, and a couple other databases).  And, even with them, phrasing the query is not obvious.  The correlated subquery is probably the easiest solution.  With indexes on the fields used, the performance may even be ok.

Comment: Works like a charm. And now I know I need to get a better handle on correlated subqueries.